# SQL Server 2012 is putting [brackets] around Table and Column Names

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql, ssms, configuration

When you drag the Columns folder to editor Window, the full list of Columns are added without Brackets.  If you drag columns individually they have Brackets.

Is there anyway to turn that off?  I'm unable to find anything in options, and they're really a distraction.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There isn't a way to prevent this. Microsoft feels that it is better to prevent you from shooting yourself in the foot, probably since the number of people out there who create databases, objects or columns with bad names (e.g. `my table` or `date`) or reserved keywords (e.g. `log` or `timestamp`) outnumber those who never do so.

There was a [Connect item asking for this option](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/378725/an-option-to-remove-square-brackets-from-coding), and it was very quickly dismissed and closed as "Won't Fix." And in fact [many more users were asking that square brackets be added to places where they previously didn't work](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/544232/ssms-dragging-column-names-to-query-window-doesnt-add-square-brackets).

Comment: Secondary discussion on this answer has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49697/discussion-on-answer-by-aaron-bertrand-sql-server-2012-is-putting-brackets-aro).

Answer (score 11):

If you are running SSMS 2017 at least v17.6, there is now an option to turn this off.  In the options dialog, go to "SQL Server Object Explorer" and then to "Commands".  Under the "Drag/Drop" heading is a new option "Surround object names with brackets when dragged".  By default, this is set to True, so just change it to False.  SSMS may need to be restarted to make the change effective.

Note:  Any objects that need the brackets (eg. with spaces or other whitespace/non-alphanumeric characters, reserved keywords) will still have brackets when drag/dropped.

Comment: Yes, it's an improvement.  But if you right-click a table and choose Select..., it still brackets the column names.

Answer (score 4):

SSMS 17.6 added the ability to turn that off.

Here's how to do it:

Tools > Options > SQL Server Object Explorer > Commands, under the Drag/Drop section set "Surround object names with brackets when dragged" to False.

According to Microsoft, Names that include spaces or closing brackets will always be escaped.

Comment: @Gordon Bell correctly stated in another comment in this thread that right-clicking a table> select will still insert brackets. Also, this answer is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

While there isn't any option that I am aware of to turn off this feature, a simple `ctrl+h` and then replace both `[` and `]` with an empty space will quickly remove the brackets from the generated t-sql scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I heard ssms 2017 v17.6 solved the issue with a setting configuration. but I haven't figured out how it can be set.

Comment: Technically this answers the question, but it's not a terrifically *useful* answer as it stands.....